# VBA excel: Sumproduct to find weighted average

Tags: excel, vba

Need help on a simple VBA .

I created one that will look to columns  C6 to H6 , if it includes the word "include" then it will average the values in C7 to H7.

The code below works to get the average, how do I upgrade it to do the sumproduct so I get a wt average?

The Excel formula is

```
SUMPRODUCT(C7:H7,C8:H8)/SUM(C8:H8)
```

Now I need to do a wt average. Using sum product I can get the answers, but how will I do it in VBA to make it dynamic and ppl can change the include values

```
Sub SuperAvgL1()
    Dim columnA As Range
    Dim columnB As Range
    Dim myR
    Set columnA = [C6:H6]
    Set columnB = [C7:H7]
    Set columnC = [C8:H8]

myR = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(columnA, "Include", columnB)
Range("I7") = myR

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How is your `SUMPRODUCT()` not already dynamic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few things off the bat; ColumnC hasn't been initialized, it's never a bad idea to include Option Explicit because it'll help catch errors later. Also it's a little odd that you're calling your Ranges columns when they're rows. Try this though and see if it works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SuperAvgL1()
    Dim rowA() As Variant
    Dim rowB() As Variant
    Dim rowC() As Variant
    Dim myResult As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Sumprod As Double
    Dim Total As Double

    rowA() = Range("C6:H6").Value
    rowB() = Range("C7:H7").Value
    rowC() = Range("C8:H8").Value

    Sumprod = 0
    Total = 0

    For i = 1 To 6
        If rowA(1, i) = "Include" Then
        Sumprod = Sumprod + rowB(1, i) * rowC(1, i)
        Total = Total + rowC(1, i)
        End if

    Next i
    Range("I7").Value = Sumprod / Total

End Sub
```

Comment: Its missing an `End If` before the `Next i` at the bottom

Comment: Good catch! fixed it.